# How to test Bobby Tables SQL Injection in Python?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to test SQL injection from this picture in Python 3.x:
[image]

Source: https://xkcd.com/327/

This example of SQL injection is mentioned in the Python SQLite3 library doc page https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html. I tried to test this out in python code, but got warning: "sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time." Are they already fixed this vulnerability? Am I doing something wrong?

Code snippet:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE test(firstname text, lastname text)''')
c.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES ('John','Doe')")

firstname = "John'; DROP TABLE test;"
c.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE firstname = '%s'" % firstname)
for i in c:
    print(i)

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE firstname = '%s'" % firstname)
sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time.
```

Comment: Rather looks like *you* fixed it. By using a function that only allows one statement. Try `executescript`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executescript

Comment: But in Python SQLite3 library doc page they are using execute function with this example.

Answer (score 1):

c.execute(...) allows for only one statement. Use c.executescript(...) or c.executemany(...).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but in Python SQLite3 library doc page they are using execute function with this example.